# Sitemap (XML) partially works on GitHub Pages and cannot be fetched by Google Search Console

Tags: xml, github-pages, sitemap, google-search-console

I have a site with a custom domain hosted on GitHub Pages. I've added a sitemap file to my repository with the name `sitemap.xml`. I am able to access it by going to https://example.com/sitemap; however, https://example.com/sitemap.xml returns a 404 error.

Furthermore, when I try to add the aforementioned sitemap to Google Search Console, it cannot fetch it. I've tried both URLs and neither works.

I am not using Jekyll or any other framework. What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a `.nojekyll` file to my repository solved the problem. I guess GitHub Pages assumed I was using Jekyll and incorrectly compiled my website.

Comment: I've just encountered the same problem. I added the `.nojekyll` file, but Google search console still fails to fetch it. Did it work for you?

Comment: @gourabix Yes, it did work for me... Could you please show me your repository? Maybe I could help!

Comment: This answer worked for my GitHub pages repository.